# jQuery event becoming unattached on load of partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the jQuery fileupload plug-in (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) with an MVC4 app.

The file upload functionality (upload and table of uploaded files) are contained in a partial view.

So I have a number of views which contain the file upload partial view. When a file is uploaded, the Save action of the Attachment controller is fired. This handles the storing of the file and then retrieves the updated list of files for this particular area of the site. The view is then returned to the fileupload jQuery and this then injects the Html into a div in the parent page (#_attachments).

All this works fine in that everything renders correctly. The issue I am having is that after a file upload is performed and the partial view is reloaded via jQuery, the fileupload no longer works.

It appears that this may be due to the event no longer being attached to the #fileUpload control. I have tried using the 'on' method but this doesn't seem to work either.

**Partial View Script**

```
$(function () {
        $('#fileUpload').fileupload({
            url: "/Attachment/Save",
            done: function (e, data) {
                // "data.result" will contain the response data
                $("#fileUploadProgress").hide();
                $("#_attachments").html(data.result);
            },
            progressall: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $("#fileUploadProgress").show();
                $("#fileUploadProgress .bar").css("width", progress + "%");
            }
        });
    });
```

**Controller/Action**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save()
        {

            // Get a reference to the file that our jQuery sent.  Even with multiple files, they will all be their own request and be the 0 index
            HttpPostedFileBase file = HttpContext.Request.Files[0];

            int ncpId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ncpId"]);
            int stage = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["stage"]);

            ncpRepository.SaveAttachmentToDb(file, CurrentUser.UserId, ncpId, stage);

            //return the partial view to refresh the list of files
            var attachments = ncpRepository.GetAttachmentsForRecord(ncpId);
            var attachmentsViewModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IQueryable<Attachment>, List<AttachmentViewModel>>(attachments);

            ViewData["Stage"] = stage;

            return PartialView("_StageAttachments", attachmentsViewModel);
        }
```

Comment: Just a guess, but are you executing the partial script every time the partial is loaded? You don't need the "on" binder here, you just need to initialize the fileupload plugin every time, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It appears that this may be due to the event no longer being attached
>   to the #fileUpload control.

Yes, that's what it looks like. Now there are a couple of issues with your code. The first issue is that you mentioned that this javascript code is inside a partial view. But partial views should not contain any scripts. Javascripts belong to separate files. Also you seem to have used the `$('#fileUpload')` selector which is an id selector. Then you said that you have many of those partial views. So you are potentially having broken DOM because you can have only one element with the specified id within your entire HTML.

So let's start fixing this situation by moving this script into a separate file (referenced from your main view once) and which will reattach the fileupload control to the new elements in the DOM:

```
var attachFileUploads = function() {
    $('.fileUpload').fileupload({
        url: "/Attachment/Save", // TODO: Never hardcode an url like that, read it from an HTML 5 data-* attribute on the corresponding file input such as data-url="@Url.Action("Save", "Attachment")"
        done: function (e, data) {
            $("#fileUploadProgress").hide();
            $("#_attachments").html(data.result);
            attachFileUploads(); // <!-- reattach the fileupload plugin
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $("#fileUploadProgress").show();
            $("#fileUploadProgress .bar").css("width", progress + "%");
        }
    });
};

$(attachFileUploads);
```

In this example I have used a class selector `$('.fileUpload')` which assumes that you can have more than one file input. Make sure you have assigned it this class and that you have gotten rid of the `id` which must be unique as mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thanks Darin. The file upload control is only in the partial view so it is only ever declared once per page, so using an id is fine in this instance. I'll update my code to reflect your approach and see how I get on.

Comment: Excellent, works great, thanks. I have also removed the hard-coded url and replaced it with the data-url value.